# Python error 'KeyError:0' assistance requested

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to implement a simple class, with instances to be added to a list. I'm getting the error 'KeyError:0' It's getting thrown in the file 'element.py' here:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
        and throws an exception if it's not there."""
        return self.attrs[key]
```

Here is my class definition, and subsequent call to it (by the way I know the code is likely verbose and non- pythonic; the 'new' in 'new to python' can't be stressed enough.):

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

import urllib.request
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class EarningsAnnouncement:
    def __init__(self, Company, Ticker, EPSEst, AnnouncementDate, AnnouncementTime):
        self.Company = Company
        self.Ticker = Ticker
        self.EPSEst = EPSEst
        self.AnnouncementDate = AnnouncementDate
        self.AnnouncementTime = AnnouncementTime


webBaseStr = 'http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/'
earningsAnnouncements = []

for dte in range(1, 30):
    dayVar = datetime.date.today()
    #currDay = str(dayVar.day)
    currDay = '22' #for debugging purposes
    currMonth = str(dayVar.month)
    currYear = str(dayVar.year)
    if (len(currDay)==1): currDay = '0' + currDay
    if (len(currMonth)==1): currMonth = '0' + currMonth
    dateStr = currYear + currMonth + currDay
    webString = webBaseStr + dateStr + '.html'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(webString) as url: page = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    tbls = soup.findAll('table')
    tbl6= tbls[6]
    rows = tbl6.findAll('tr')
    rows = rows[2:]
    for earn in rows:
        earningsAnnouncements.append(EarningsAnnouncement(earn[0], earn[1], earn[3], dateStr, earn[3]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for earn in rows:
        earningsAnnouncements.append(EarningsAnnouncement(earn[0], earn[1], earn[3], dateStr, earn[3]))
```

`earn` is a `tag` object representing a `tr` element and his desendants in the HTML. And the `[]` on a tag is used to access the **attributes** of the tag. For example:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<tr class="hello">aaa</tr><tr>bbb</tr>')
>>> trs = soup.find_all('tr')
>>> trs[0]['class']
['hello']
>>>
```

There is no attribute named `0` so a KeyError raised. If you want to access the contents of the tag, you should use `earn.contents[0]`.